# Withdrawal of uk visa application - will that affect my future application?

Tags: visas

I've recently withdrew my UK tier-5 YMS visa application due to my concern on continuing my study in the UK. I have given a letter explaining in detail to the UKVI. Will that affect my future application of the same visa? Does withdrawal lead to a bad record?

Thanks

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue. You are allowed to change your mind.

Comment: @Jo Lee, did you reapply after the withdrawal?